# Can't Download Index Data from Yahoo R

Tags: r, indexing, get, assets

So, I want to download an index's data but can't get the data.  The problem is that Yahoo.finance sees index's tickers as having a ^ before them, for example, ^VIX not VIX.  Unfotunentally, my code doesn't like that.  I can't find any functions or alternative ways to call this data.  Also, I really don't want to change the platform from which I get my data from, that would be a HUGE pain in the butt for the rest of my code.

I have tried putting in the ^ with the asset, and it won't download data.  I've also tried calling the data without the ^ and that gives the wrong data.

```
asset <- "VIX"
ticker <- "VIX"

start.date <- as.Date('2009-09-01')

getSymbols(ticker, src='yahoo', from=start.date)

Adj.Close <- get(ticker)[,6]
```

When I put this in I end up getting this message:

```
Error in get(ticker) : object '^VIX' not found
```

Thank you for your time, regardless of whether or not you know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm your issue. There is no need here for a leading `"^"` symbol.

Running

```
library(quantmod)
ticker <- "VIX"
start.date <- as.Date('2009-09-01')
getSymbols(ticker, src='yahoo', from=start.date)
```

will automatically store the output in an `xts` object called `VIX`

```
head(get(ticker))
#           VIX.Open VIX.High VIX.Low VIX.Close VIX.Volume VIX.Adjusted
#2014-12-04  28200.4  30096.9 27953.0   28447.7     811330      28447.7
#2014-12-05  26551.2  27540.7 25974.0   26056.5     377529      26056.5
#2014-12-08  25231.9  26056.5 23582.8   23582.8     367585      23582.8
#2014-12-09  23582.8  23582.8 21274.0   21274.0     570963      21274.0
#2014-12-10  19789.7  20202.0 19212.5   19295.0     539795      19295.0
#2014-12-11  18635.3  19295.0 17398.5   17728.3    1053637      17728.3
```

Note that can you avoid the `get` step if you avoid auto-assigning the output of `getSymbols` to the current environment:

```
res <- getSymbols("VIX", src='yahoo', from=start.date, auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but there is still a problem.  I tried the index TNX and it only gave me 5 data points, which had the wrong prices.  Any ideas?

Comment: @L.Zingg That seems to be a different issue; I would suggest [closing this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com) and then asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Maurits seeks data for the VIX Index, in which case I find it necessary to include the carat in the ticker. Building on the previous answer we can see that a valid object is returned when we use the "^VIX" ticker.

```
library(quantmod)
start.date <- as.Date('2009-09-01')
ticker <- "^VIX"
getSymbols(ticker, src='yahoo', from=start.date)

[1] "^VIX"
```

However, `get`is unable to find that object:

```
head(get(ticker))
Error in get(ticker) : object '^VIX' not found
```

But, using "VIX" rather than "^VIX" with `get`returns the desired result:

```
head(get("VIX"))
           VIX.Open VIX.High VIX.Low VIX.Close VIX.Volume VIX.Adjusted
2009-09-01    26.01    29.23   26.00     29.15          0        29.15
2009-09-02    29.14    29.57   28.41     28.90          0        28.90
2009-09-03    28.90    28.90   26.98     27.10          0        27.10
2009-09-04    26.98    26.98   24.86     25.26          0        25.26
2009-09-08    25.26    26.15   25.26     25.62          0        25.62
2009-09-09    25.66    25.93   24.23     24.32          0        24.32
```